# SQL join conundrum

Tags: mysql, sql, join

SQL conundrum here.

In simplified form, I have 3 tables:

**test**

```
tnum     name     
-------------
1        A        
2        B
```

**section**

```
tnum     snum    num_of_qs
-------------------------
1        1        6
1        2        7
```

**question**

```
tnum     qnum     
-------------
1        1        
1        2
```

Each table obviously has more data than that.

The issue is that there is no link between the `section` table and the `question` table except for the `tnum`. I'm making this SQL call:

```
SELECT * FROM test t 
LEFT JOIN section s ON s.tnum = t.tnum
LEFT JOIN question q ON q.tnum = t.tnum...
```

What happens is that a complete set of questions gets sent for each section. So if there are 100 questions divided into 17 sections, I get 1700 questions.

Is there a way I can get all questions and all sections in one call without duplication?

Thanks

Comment: How should the desired result set look like?

Comment: Can you reformat the database? I think the problem is in your modeling. A test consists of one or more sections, and a section consists of one or more questions. Question should be snum, qnum.

Comment: @raina77ow  I loop through and sort the set into arrays and then use json_encode before I return the AJAX call, so I don't really mind. The key is I only want one set of answers.

Comment: I could, I guess. I've previously decided not to do so for a couple of reasons, but it's not irreversible. I could just make a separate call to get the sections, too. That's pretty ugly, though.

Comment: Nick, raina77ow's question wasn't asking what you answered. This was to understand what you really want and from example provided, you should show the expected result.

Comment: Is there a way to know which question belongs to which section? Are the questions ordered by sections?

Comment: @Sameer  Yes, that's right. Each section record has the section name and the number of questions. So if section 1 has 7 questions, it covers questions 1 through 7. Section 2 then begins at question 8. I wanted to keep the question data independent of sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database structure should be (only the must-be fields left, excluding names' columns etc.):

Questions:

- **qnum**
- snum

Sections

- **snum**
- tnum

Tests

- **tnum**

(bold - primary keys)

and your query then should be something like:

```
SELECT
    q.qnum,
    s.snum,
    t.tnum
FROM
    questions q
    LEFT JOIN sections s ON q.snum = s.snum
    LEFT JOIN tests t ON s.tnum = t.tnum
```

Comment: @nick If questions belong to sections, there is no benefit at all in keeping the question data independent of the section data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ts.tnum,
    ts.name,
    ts.snum,
    ts.num_of_qs,
    q.qnum
FROM
(SELECT     
    t.tnum,
    t.name,
    s.snum,
    s.num_of_qs
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN section s ON s.tnum = t.tnum) As ts
LEFT JOIN question q ON q.tnum = ts.tnum
```

try above sql statement. i create a virtual "ts" table with join test and section table. this ts table finally join with question table.

Comment: You alone actually answered the question as I posed it, but it's probably overkill in reality. I should just bite the bullet and add the section data onto the question table. +1 nonetheless :)

Comment: Yes, Fthiella Because i am using here sub query virtual table. it will reduce performance.